# Javascript set title with new lines

Tags: javascript, newline, title

None of these makes the title appear with a new line.

```
ele.title = 'abc &#10; ABC';
ele.setAttribute('title', 'abc &#10; ABC');
```

If i load the page with that element having the same title, then it would be with a new line. I've even tried with different new line markings.

Comment: Maybe try: `\n` . Although the title element probably won't allow any linebreaks.

Comment: It's cazy! if i set it through the console - it works. But what i do is to get the text from PHP and then set it as a title. There - nothing works

Comment: Look at the generated source (right click -> view page source). It's possible that PHP escapes the ampersand or does something else to the text.

Comment: Nope. It's through AJAX, and the text received is not escaped - just as it is supposed to be

Comment: Try `&#13` instead of `&#10`. `&#13` is a `C`arriage `R`eturn

Comment: Why do you want a newline in the title? Most window systems won't display window titles with multiple lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me

```
ele.title =  'abc' + "\u000d" + 'ABC';
```

This is the Unicode escape sequence for the carriage return (CR). I am not sure why HTML entity names or numbers do not work in the title, but the Unicode escape sequence is what works.

Comment: It was crazy ... even `"string".replace('&#10;', "\u000d")` didn't work. I had to `split()` and then make a loop to add it to the end of every each array piece.

Comment: This saved my bacon - seems the only way to get it to work with Vue when you have a title element where you want to add lines on conditionally.